# Best way to move a rectangle in XNA/C#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, bounce, pong

I'm a starter in XNA and I'm trying to make a pong-game.
I've been able to make a pong game, but all the code was in one class. So I wanted to try to add a little bit of OOP and I've made a class for the ball and one for the pad.

The ball moves perfectly, but I don't seem to able to make the ball bounce from the pads.

These are the codes I use:
**To move the pads**
*Game1.cs*

```
#region left
    if (_KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.W) || _KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
        Left.MoveUp();
    else if (_KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        Left.MoveDown();
#endregion

#region right
    if (_KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        Right.MoveUp();
    else if (_KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        Right.MoveDown();
#endregion
```

*pad.cs*

```
public void MoveUp() {
    if (!paused)
        RecPad.Offset(0, -speed);

    CheckBorders();
}

public void MoveDown() {
    if (!paused)
        RecPad.Offset(0, speed);

    CheckBorders();
}

private void CheckBorders() {
    MathHelper.Clamp(recPad.Y, borders.Top, borders.Bottom - recPad.Height);
}
```

**To check if the ball bounces**
*ball.cs*

```
public void CheckBounce() {
    if ((myBounds.Intersects(left) && movement.X < 0) || (myBounds.Intersects(right) && movement.X > 0))
            movement.X *= -1;
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch sBatch, Texture2D texture, Color color, Rectangle left, Rectangle right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;

    Move();

    sBatch.Begin();
    sBatch.Draw(texture, myBounds, color);
    sBatch.End();
}
```

*pad.cs*

```
public Rectangle RecPad {
    get { return recPad; }
    private set { recPad = value; }
}
```

*Game1.cs*

```
Ball.Draw(spriteBatch, ball, Color.White, Left.RecPad, Right.RecPad);
```

**I seemed to get the pads back to work**
The problem seems to be solved by using the originel recPad instead of the constructor RecPad
Now I only need to get my boundries working, because the MathHelper.Clamp doesn't seem to work
See [my code](http://pastebin.com/DgquAJbk) for more info

This code now fixed my border-problem

```
private void CheckBorders() {
        if (recPad.Top < borders.Top)
            recPad.Location = new Point(recPad.X, borders.Top);
        if (recPad.Bottom > borders.Bottom)
            recPad.Location = new Point(recPad.X, borders.Bottom - recPad.Height);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This immediately stands out to me (from CheckBounce):

```
    movement.X *= 1;
```

Could be a copying error, or you forgot to put a '-'.

Also, consider using the Rectangle.Contains/Intersects method(s) to streamline some collision code, and MathHelper.Clamp to keep your paddles in bounds. This is more just for future reference, since your methods work, but it's nice to take advantage of the helpful tools in XNA.

Edit: Concerning those 'helpful tools':

The Rectangle class has the methods Intersect and Contains, which can tell you if that rectangle is intersecting another rectangle or containing a certain point, respectively. You say your ball is just a top left position and a texture, but I see in your collision checking you also check for the radius of the ball. I think you'd have an easier time defining a Rectangle bounding area for your ball and using the Intersects method to check for collision. That simplifies your collision code to:

```
public void CheckBounce()
{
    if (myBounds.Intersects(LeftPaddle.Bounds) || myBounds.Intersects(RightPaddle.Bounds))
        movement.X *= -1;
}
```

Fairly simple, but not entirely safe-- if the ball manages to move far enough into a paddle that one frame of movement wouldn't free it from that paddle's bounds, you'd be stuck perpetually inverting the X velocity, producing a 'stuck ball' effect. So we can add just a bit more checking code to avoid that:

```
public void CheckBounce()
{
    if ((myBounds.Intersects(LeftPaddle.Bounds) && movement.X < 0) ||
     (myBounds.Intersects(RightPaddle.Bounds) && movement.X > 0))
        movement.X *= -1;
}
```

I apologize if the inline conditionals are a little too dense. What this means is, if the ball is moving left and hits the right paddle, invert the X. Likewise, if it's moving right and hits the left paddle, invert the X. This removes the 'sticking'.

Now, as for MathHelper.Clamp, in your situation I would use it to restrict paddle movement. MathHelper.Clamp simply clamps a value between an upper and lower bound. It's the equivalent of using Math.Min, then Math.Max.

```
private void CheckBorders()
{
    //clamps a       value  to a   min  and a           max
    MathHelper.Clamp(recPad.Y, borders.Top, borders.Bottom - recPad.Height);
}
```

This clamps the Y position of your rectangle between the top of your borders, and the bottom of your borders minus the height of the rectangle. That last bit keeps the bottom of your rectangle from clipping the bottom of the borders by taking the height into account.

Comment: +1, assuming it's like classic Pong, in which the paddles are always vertically aligned, then just inverting the X velocity should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you give me more info about the techniques you've mentioned?  
BTW: the ball isn't a Rectangle, just a Texture2D with a Vector2 as topLeft position

Comment: Damn! My pad's don't seem to move anymore? I believe it's caused by the _RecPad.Offset(0,speed);_ but I'm not sure

Comment: But, uh.. did making that '1' a '-1' work? If not I'll take a closer look at your bouncing code. Anyways, I'll edit my answer for more details on suggested implementations of Rectangle methods and Clamp.

Comment: Also, use breakpoints and debug any lines of code you're not sure of. If speed is 0, then the pads won't move. It's fairly easy to set a breakpoint there when you expect movement and see.

Comment: I've changed the code like you've seuggested (I'll edit my post), but my pads still don't move :s Debugging with breakpoints didn't help, speeds stays 5 (I don't have a variable speed yet).

Comment: All I can say is keep stepping through the code. Check the value of the position of the Rectangle before and after you do your move method. If it hasn't changed, look inside the move method and see if the Offset method actually changed it. If it has, then it must have been reset somewhere-- find out where. Bear in mind that Rectangle is a struct type, so if it is passed as a parameter into a function and modified these modifications will not be persistent outside of the scope of the function. If all else fails, disregard whatever you changed on my suggestion and rebuild from what worked before

Comment: @A-Type I seem to get the movement back to work. Looks like using the constructor RecPad caused the problems. I know use recpad everywhere in my code, I also had to make it public, as I use it for the bounce-code in my ball.cs. _Mathelper.Clamp_ doesn't seem to help, so I'll return to the old code for the boundries

Comment: MathHelper.Clamp in general won't necessarily improve the functionality of your code, but it will cut down on the number of lines you need to write for common value clamping. That's really most of what the MathHelper does; just save you some time with common math operations. Just remember it in the future :)